# Is it possible to submit the time that's obtained by javascript to a Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This button show the current elapsed time of video media

```
<button name="test" onclick="alert(Math.floor(document.getElementById('video').currentTime) + 'secs elapsed!');">Show elapsed time</button>
```

This elapsed time obviously changes at every second.

Is it possible to submit this elapsed time to a form?
How can I customize the code below?

```
<form action="/comments" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="comment[body]" size="50" />
    <input type="hidden" name="comment[elapsed_time]" value="???????" />
    <button type="submit" >Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use jQuery to set the value before the form is submitted

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  var video = $("#video"),
      time  = Math.floor(video.currentTime) + 'secs elapsed!');
  $(this).find("input[name=comment\\[elapsed_time\\]").val(time);
});
```

---

If you (can) add an `id` attribute to the input, it would be easier

```
<input type="hidden" name="comment[elapsed_time]" id="comment_elapsed_time">
```

Then your jQuery becomes this

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {
  var video = $("#video"),
      time  = Math.floor(video.currentTime) + 'secs elapsed!');
  $("#comment_elapsed_time").val(time);
});
```

Comment: If using jQuery, you can use `var video = $("#video");`

Comment: You can almost do that, see below.

Answer (score 2):

HTML change:

```
<form action="/comments" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="comment[body]" size="50" />
    <input id="elapsed_time" type="hidden" name="comment[elapsed_time]" value="???????" />
    <button type="submit" >Submit!</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('#elapsed_time').val($('#video')[0].currentTime);

  //now submit the form if you want tp
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: If you are going to use jQuery, why not refactor to `$('#video').currentTime`

Comment: slight mistake in there with using [0]. corrected that and added it to my answer..thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

Without using jQuery, you can change your html to:

```
<form action="/comments" method="post" onsubmit="onFormSubmit()" >
    <input type="text" name="comment[body]" size="50" />
    <input type="hidden" name="comment[elapsed_time]" />
    <button type="submit" >Submit!</button>
</form>
```

and add this JavaScript in your `<head>`:

```
<script>
    function onFormSubmit() {
        var element = document.getElementsByName("comment[elapsed_time]")[0];
        element.value = Math.floor(document.getElementById('video').currentTime);
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add some ids to your form to make it easily to manipulate, it is not necessary.

```
<form action="/comments" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="comment[body]" size="50" />
    <input id="elapsedTimeTextBox" type="hidden" name="comment[elapsed_time]" value="???????" />
    <button id="submitButton" type="submit" >Submit!</button>
</form>
```

hook an event in the submit button like this if you use jQuery

```
$('#submitButton').click (function () {
   $('#elapsedTimeTextBox').val(Math.floor(document.getElementById('video').currentTime);
});
```